# SUM e GROUP BY duplicando valores

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ao tentar somar e agrupar valores, verifiquei que o `SUM` e `GROUP BY` não estão comportando-se da maneira que espero e não consegui identificar a causa. Efetuando a consulta abaixo

```
SELECT representantes.cod_representante,
       representantes.nome_abrev,
       (itens_notasfiscais.quantidade_faturada) AS qtde_prod,
       (itens_notasfiscais.quantidade_faturada*itens_notasfiscais.valor_unitario) AS valor_total,
       (itens_notasfiscais.quantidade_faturada*tabela_precos_produtos.valor_canal) AS valor_canal
FROM notasfiscais
INNER JOIN 
(
    (
        (
            (
                (
                    tabela_precos
                INNER JOIN (
                    itens_notasfiscais
                            INNER JOIN tabela_precos_produtos ON itens_notasfiscais.cod_produto=tabela_precos_produtos.cod_produto
                            ) ON tabela_precos.cod_tabela = tabela_precos_produtos.cod_tabela
                )
                INNER JOIN representantes ON itens_notasfiscais.cod_representante = representantes.cod_representante
            )
                INNER JOIN clientes ON (tabela_precos.uf=clientes.estado)
                AND (itens_notasfiscais.cod_cliente=clientes.cod_cliente)
            )
        INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.cod = 38
    )
    INNER JOIN canal_vendas ON clientes.cod_canal = canal_vendas.cod_canal
) ON notasfiscais.cod_notafiscal = itens_notasfiscais.cod_notafiscal
INNER JOIN ac_pedido ap ON (
    ap.fk_Cliente = itens_notasfiscais.cod_cliente
    AND ap.fk_Representante = representantes.cod_representante
    AND ap.pedido_cliente = notasfiscais.pedido_cliente
    AND ap.pedido_representante = notasfiscais.pedido_repres
)
INNER JOIN metas m ON (
    m.cod_produto = tabela_precos_produtos.cod_produto
    AND m.ano = 2016
    AND m.cod_representante IN (representantes.cod_representante)
)
WHERE 
(
    (
        (itens_notasfiscais.valor_unitario) < (CASE month(ap.data_emissao) WHEN 1 THEN m.jan_valor WHEN 2 THEN m.fev_valor WHEN 3 THEN m.mar_valor WHEN 4 THEN m.abr_valor WHEN 5 THEN m.mai_valor WHEN 6 THEN m.jun_valor WHEN 7 THEN m.jul_valor WHEN 8 THEN m.ago_valor WHEN 9 THEN m.stm_valor WHEN 10 THEN m.out_valor WHEN 11 THEN m.nov_valor WHEN 12 THEN m.dez_valor END)
    )
    AND ((tabela_precos_produtos.ate)=999999)
    AND ((tabela_precos_produtos.cod_canal)>=1)
)
AND month(notasfiscais.data_emissao) = 8
AND year(notasfiscais.data_emissao) = 2016
AND notasfiscais.bonificacao = 0
AND representantes.cod_representante IN (SELECT cod_representante FROM usuarios_usuarios WHERE cod_gerente = 38)
AND PATINDEX('%' + CAST(itens_notasfiscais.cod_grupo AS NVARCHAR) + '%',usuarios.grupos) > 0
AND tabela_precos_produtos.cod_canal IN (clientes.cod_canal)
GROUP BY representantes.cod_representante,
         representantes.nome_abrev,
         itens_notasfiscais.valor_unitario,
         itens_notasfiscais.quantidade_faturada,
         tabela_precos_produtos.valor_canal
ORDER BY representantes.cod_representante,
         sum(itens_notasfiscais.quantidade_faturada*itens_notasfiscais.valor_unitario) DESC
```

Obtenho o seguinte resultado:

```
cod_representante |nome_abrev   |qtde_prod |valor_total        |valor_canal        |
------------------|-------------|----------|-------------------|-------------------|
39                |CONVEL REPR. |150.0     |12334.08           |14016.0            |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |500.0     |11221.85           |15000.0            |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |50.0      |3429.8             |3897.5             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |500.0     |8603.45            |11500.0            |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |150.0     |8187.240000000001  |10396.5            |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |20.0      |1204.54            |1368.8             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |50.0      |1993.9499999999998 |2532.0             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |150.0     |5981.849999999999  |7596.0             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |20.0      |1329.1399999999999 |1687.8             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |100.0     |4821.52            |4990.0             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |30.0      |4593.33            |5219.700000000001  |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |30.0      |4545.549           |4828.5             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |30.0      |1500.309           |1704.8999999999999 |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |30.0      |2057.88            |2338.5             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |20.0      |1000.21            |1136.6             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |40.0      |1928.612           |2191.6             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |20.0      |3814.63            |4269.599999999999  |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |20.0      |900.1099999999999  |1143.0             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |83.0      |3309.957           |4203.12            |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |20.0      |3062.22            |3479.8             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |20.0      |1496.1799999999998 |1700.2             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |70.0      |2791.5299999999997 |3544.8             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |20.0      |1371.92            |1559.0             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |50.0      |2729.08            |3465.5             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |50.0      |2514.62            |3056.5             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |50.0      |2500.5299999999997 |2841.5             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |50.0      |2500.52            |2685.0             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |15.0      |1233.4095          |1401.6             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |50.0      |2410.75            |2495.0             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |50.0      |2250.29            |2857.5             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |20.0      |1111.26            |1262.8             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |20.0      |1089.6200000000001 |1238.1999999999998 |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |10.0      |1033.83            |1312.8             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |20.0      |2067.66            |2625.6             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |40.0      |2000.42            |2148.0             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |15.0      |996.8595           |1265.85            |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |20.0      |964.3000000000001  |1095.8             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |5.0       |953.66             |1083.7             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |41.0      |1845.2296000000001 |2343.15            |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |15.0      |1732.9005000000002 |1941.9             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |30.0      |1637.451           |2079.3             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |30.0      |1637.4389999999999 |2079.3             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |35.0      |1575.1995          |2000.25            |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |15.0      |1550.7495000000001 |1969.2             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |10.0      |1531.11            |1739.9             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |20.0      |1371.93            |1559.0             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |15.0      |660.3195           |838.5              |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |10.0      |639.84             |812.5              |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |15.0      |1269.8595          |1612.5             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |15.0      |1269.8505          |1612.5             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |10.0      |581.5699999999999  |738.5              |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |20.0      |1095.25            |1390.8000000000002 |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |20.0      |1091.6299999999999 |1386.2             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |15.0      |996.8595           |1228.5             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |15.0      |818.7194999999999  |978.45             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |15.0      |818.7194999999999  |1039.65            |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |2.0       |381.46             |433.48             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |5.0       |757.59             |860.9000000000001  |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |3.0       |572.1899999999999  |650.22             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |10.0      |547.63             |695.4000000000001  |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |5.0       |516.92             |656.4              |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |5.0       |516.9100000000001  |647.3000000000001  |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |5.0       |255.66             |324.65000000000003 |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |10.0      |511.32             |649.3000000000001  |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |3.0       |459.33000000000004 |521.97             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |3.0       |454.55009999999993 |516.54             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |5.0       |423.28000000000003 |533.3              |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |5.0       |423.28000000000003 |537.5              |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |5.0       |374.04             |425.05             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |10.0      |339.33             |430.90000000000003 |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |5.0       |153.96             |195.5              |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |5.0       |277.82             |315.7              |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |5.0       |240.7              |305.65000000000003 |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |5.0       |199.39             |240.95             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |5.0       |194.32             |246.75             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |2.0       |61.58              |78.2               |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |1.0       |151.52             |172.18             |
39                |CONVEL REPR. |1.0       |126.3              |160.38             |
41                |E.M. REPRE.  |20.0      |1120.042           |1298.6000000000001 |
41                |E.M. REPRE.  |6.0       |695.9939999999999  |787.6800000000001  |
41                |E.M. REPRE.  |10.0      |580.0              |649.3000000000001  |
41                |E.M. REPRE.  |7.0       |515.3666000000001  |545.65             |
41                |E.M. REPRE.  |10.0      |477.78799999999995 |506.4              |
41                |E.M. REPRE.  |10.0      |455.599            |493.5              |
41                |E.M. REPRE.  |5.0       |326.49299999999994 |342.2              |
41                |E.M. REPRE.  |4.0       |243.3668           |252.56             |
41                |E.M. REPRE.  |3.0       |240.59520000000003 |255.03000000000003 |
41                |E.M. REPRE.  |3.0       |229.97820000000002 |243.75             |
41                |E.M. REPRE.  |3.0       |209.01030000000003 |221.54999999999998 |
41                |E.M. REPRE.  |3.0       |182.517            |185.73             |
41                |E.M. REPRE.  |3.0       |155.0667           |164.37             |
41                |E.M. REPRE.  |2.0       |121.6822           |126.66             |
41                |E.M. REPRE.  |3.0       |161.454            |170.49             |
64                |SESAN        |30.0      |1460.0310000000002 |1854.0             |
64                |SESAN        |15.0      |730.0095           |927.0              |
64                |SESAN        |10.0      |543.84             |618.0              |
64                |SESAN        |10.0      |486.67             |618.0              |
145               |ZANATTA MART |70.0      |4874.099999999999  |4790.8             |
```

Para uma análise rápida, vejamos o penúltimo representante chamado aqui de `SESAN`, a soma da terceira coluna (`qtde`) seria **65**.

Agora adicionando o `SUM` e o `GROUP BY` apenas pelo representante:

```
SELECT representantes.cod_representante,
       representantes.nome_abrev,
       sum(itens_notasfiscais.quantidade_faturada) AS qtde_prod,
       sum(itens_notasfiscais.quantidade_faturada*itens_notasfiscais.valor_unitario) AS valor_total,
       sum(itens_notasfiscais.quantidade_faturada*tabela_precos_produtos.valor_canal) AS valor_canal

...
GROUP BY representantes.cod_representante,
         representantes.nome_abrev
ORDER BY sum(itens_notasfiscais.quantidade_faturada*itens_notasfiscais.valor_unitario) DESC
```

O resultado agrupado retorna:

```
cod_representante |nome_abrev   |qtde_prod |valor_total        |valor_canal |
------------------|-------------|----------|-------------------|------------|
39                |CONVEL REPR. |3825.0    |193288.5317        |231683.37   |
41                |E.M. REPRE.  |181.0     |11268.451999999997 |12316.45    |
64                |SESAN        |130.0     |6441.101000000001  |8034.0      |
145               |ZANATTA MART |70.0      |4874.099999999999  |4790.8      |
```

Analisemos novamente o caso do penúltimo representante, `SESAN`, os valores duplicaram e invés da coluna `qtde_prod` retornar **65**, retornou **130**

Qual poderia ser a causa desse comportamento?

Comment: Não analisei o SELEC que você fez. mas muito provavelmente algum JOIN tá furado e trazendo resultados duplicados.

Comment: @lcssanches os resultados só são duplicados quando aplico o `SUM`, o `SELECT` retorna corretamente as quantidades e valores. Não vejo como algum `JOIN` possa estar causando isso apenas com a aplicação do `SUM`

Comment: Não entendi o motivo do `-1` na questão...

Comment: Nao foi eu rs. Marcaram -1 em uma questao minha tambem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apesar de não conhecer à estrutura do seu banco, posso lhe propor uma solução rapida para o seu caso.

Vejo que na sua primeira consulta, você tem o seguinte group by.:

```
GROUP BY representantes.cod_representante,
         representantes.nome_abrev,
         itens_notasfiscais.valor_unitario,
         itens_notasfiscais.quantidade_faturada,
         tabela_precos_produtos.valor_canal
```

Então sem este GROUP BY, a sua primeira consulta deve trazer 8 registros com `cod_representante = 64` e `nome_abrev = SESAN`.

Então se você adicionar à seguinte coluna no seu `SELECT`: `COUNT(1) as qtd_registros`, você deve obter um resultado similar ao seguinte.

```
cod_representante |nome_abrev   |qtde_prod |valor_total        |valor_canal        |qtd_registros |
------------------|-------------|----------|-------------------|-------------------|--------------|
64                |SESAN        |30.0      |1460.0310000000002 |1854.0             |2             |
64                |SESAN        |15.0      |730.0095           |927.0              |2             |
64                |SESAN        |10.0      |543.84             |618.0              |2             |
64                |SESAN        |10.0      |486.67             |618.0              |2             |
```

Isto ocorre por que neste caso você não está à soma os valores.

Então você deverá transformar esta primeira query em uma subquery, a fim de fazer uma prétriagem dos dados, para então realizar o segundo agrupamento.

```
WITH CTE_Representantes AS (
    SELECT representantes.cod_representante,
        representantes.nome_abrev,
        (itens_notasfiscais.quantidade_faturada) AS qtde_prod,
        (itens_notasfiscais.quantidade_faturada*itens_notasfiscais.valor_unitario) AS valor_total,
        (itens_notasfiscais.quantidade_faturada*tabela_precos_produtos.valor_canal) AS valor_canal
    FROM notasfiscais
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        (
            (
                (
                    (
                        tabela_precos
                    INNER JOIN (
                        itens_notasfiscais
                                INNER JOIN tabela_precos_produtos ON itens_notasfiscais.cod_produto=tabela_precos_produtos.cod_produto
                                ) ON tabela_precos.cod_tabela = tabela_precos_produtos.cod_tabela
                    )
                    INNER JOIN representantes ON itens_notasfiscais.cod_representante = representantes.cod_representante
                )
                    INNER JOIN clientes ON (tabela_precos.uf=clientes.estado)
                    AND (itens_notasfiscais.cod_cliente=clientes.cod_cliente)
                )
            INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.cod = 38
        )
        INNER JOIN canal_vendas ON clientes.cod_canal = canal_vendas.cod_canal
    ) ON notasfiscais.cod_notafiscal = itens_notasfiscais.cod_notafiscal
    INNER JOIN ac_pedido ap ON (
        ap.fk_Cliente = itens_notasfiscais.cod_cliente
        AND ap.fk_Representante = representantes.cod_representante
        AND ap.pedido_cliente = notasfiscais.pedido_cliente
        AND ap.pedido_representante = notasfiscais.pedido_repres
    )
    INNER JOIN metas m ON (
        m.cod_produto = tabela_precos_produtos.cod_produto
        AND m.ano = 2016
        AND m.cod_representante IN (representantes.cod_representante)
    )
    WHERE 
    (
        (
            (itens_notasfiscais.valor_unitario) < (CASE month(ap.data_emissao) WHEN 1 THEN m.jan_valor WHEN 2 THEN m.fev_valor WHEN 3 THEN m.mar_valor WHEN 4 THEN m.abr_valor WHEN 5 THEN m.mai_valor WHEN 6 THEN m.jun_valor WHEN 7 THEN m.jul_valor WHEN 8 THEN m.ago_valor WHEN 9 THEN m.stm_valor WHEN 10 THEN m.out_valor WHEN 11 THEN m.nov_valor WHEN 12 THEN m.dez_valor END)
        )
        AND ((tabela_precos_produtos.ate)=999999)
        AND ((tabela_precos_produtos.cod_canal)>=1)
    )
    AND month(notasfiscais.data_emissao) = 8
    AND year(notasfiscais.data_emissao) = 2016
    AND notasfiscais.bonificacao = 0
    AND representantes.cod_representante IN (SELECT cod_representante FROM usuarios_usuarios WHERE cod_gerente = 38)
    AND PATINDEX('%' + CAST(itens_notasfiscais.cod_grupo AS NVARCHAR) + '%',usuarios.grupos) > 0
    AND tabela_precos_produtos.cod_canal IN (clientes.cod_canal)
    GROUP BY representantes.cod_representante,
             representantes.nome_abrev,
             itens_notasfiscais.valor_unitario,
             itens_notasfiscais.quantidade_faturada,
             tabela_precos_produtos.valor_canal
)

SELECT cod_representante,
       nome_abrev,
       sum(qtde_prod) AS qtde_prod,
       sum(valor_total) AS valor_total,
       sum(qvalor_canal) AS valor_canal
GROUP BY cod_representante,
         nome_abrev
ORDER BY sum(valor_total) DESC
```

**Nota Pessoal**

achei estranho à seguinte construção:

```
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        (
            (
                (
                    (
                        tabela_precos
                    INNER JOIN (
                        itens_notasfiscais
                                INNER JOIN tabela_precos_produtos ON itens_notasfiscais.cod_produto=tabela_precos_produtos.cod_produto
                                ) ON tabela_precos.cod_tabela = tabela_precos_produtos.cod_tabela
                    )
                    INNER JOIN representantes ON itens_notasfiscais.cod_representante = representantes.cod_representante
                )
                    INNER JOIN clientes ON (tabela_precos.uf=clientes.estado)
                    AND (itens_notasfiscais.cod_cliente=clientes.cod_cliente)
                )
            INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.cod = 38
        )
        INNER JOIN canal_vendas ON clientes.cod_canal = canal_vendas.cod_canal
    ) ON notasfiscais.cod_notafiscal = itens_notasfiscais.cod_notafiscal
```

Estes `Inner Joins` são no minimo confusos, acredito que aqui caberia um refactory em prou do seu "eu futuro" ou de algum outro programador.

**Explicação Adicional**

Quanto eu disse "Isto ocorre por que neste caso você não está à soma os valores.", é por que na primeira consulta você está usando o GROUP BY para não exibir valores unicos.

Se remover o Group By, possivelmente terá algo do genero:

```
cod_representante |nome_abrev   |qtde_prod |valor_total        |valor_canal        |
------------------|-------------|----------|-------------------|-------------------|
64                |SESAN        |30.0      |1460.0310000000002 |1854.0             |
64                |SESAN        |30.0      |1460.0310000000002 |1854.0             |
64                |SESAN        |15.0      |730.0095           |927.0              |
64                |SESAN        |15.0      |730.0095           |927.0              |
64                |SESAN        |10.0      |543.84             |618.0              |
64                |SESAN        |10.0      |543.84             |618.0              |
64                |SESAN        |10.0      |486.67             |618.0              |
64                |SESAN        |10.0      |486.67             |618.0              |
```

ao aplicar o `GROUP BY` você não está à somar os valores, esta apenas ignorando as duplicações. Em nenhum momento disse que este comportamento é um problema, até por ser o comportamento desejado.

porém na sua segunda consulta, você estava somando todos os valores, quando na verdade você gostaria de ignorar as duplicações, para então realizar a soma.

Comment: TobyMosque, creio que tua solução resolveu esse "comportamento", só não entendi a parte que você diz "Isto ocorre por que neste caso você não está à soma os valores." - Como assim não está a somar?

Comment: Quanto a estrutura, realmente é estranho e precisa de um refactory, não é de minha autoria todo o script além de pertencer a um sistema legado.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade editei à resposta com uma explicação sobre à minha citação, espero que tenha entendido.

Comment: Sim, ficou bem mais claro agora, @TobyMosque. Obrigado.